# How can I display my listview that has activities inside it to alert dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I need help. I dunno how to use alertdialog in a listview. How can I implement Alertdialog in a listview that have days of a week which will open in an alert dialog because my purpose of this is only to show a small detail of an event that will occur in a day instead of going to new activity? So here is my my code:

```
    ListView listView;
    int[] truck = {R.drawable.truck_21,R.drawable.truck_21,R.drawable.truck_21,R.drawable.truck_21,R.drawable.truck_21,R.drawable.truck_21,R.drawable.truck_21};
    String[] values = new String[]{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);


    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);




            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                            Intent monday = new Intent(view.getContext(), Monday.class);
                           startActivityForResult(monday, 0);
                         break;

                        case 1:
                            Intent tuesday = new Intent(view.getContext(), Tuesday.class);
                            startActivityForResult(tuesday, 0);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            break;
                            default:

                    }

                }
            });

        }
        class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return truck.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dope,null);
                ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.truck);
                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.Monday);

                mImageView.setImageResource(truck[position]);
                mTextView.setText(values[position]);
                return view;
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: You already have actions for your onClick listener, do you want an AlertDialog shown when you click an item or a long click or a different button you click within the view. You need to clarify when you want to show the AlertDialog

Comment: I want an AlertDialog shown

Comment: when what happens? on ItemClick? cause you currently start another activity when you click an item

Comment: got it already.  I replaced with this  View sunday = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_saturday, null);
                        builderSingle.setView(sunday);
                        builderSingle.show();